# ASP.NET MVC 4 dropdownlist binding within begincollectionitem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and while I'm aware that ignorance isn't an excuse I couldn't find any helpful(to me) answers from similar questions.

**Issue:**

My `ModelState` is invalid because I've bound the id of the RoleDTO model( a model in a partial view which is in begincollectionitem ) to the dropdownlist using `Html.DropDownListFor( r => r.Id, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PossibleRoles))`. Because of that the Name property of the RoleDTO model is always empty and `ModelState` validation fails. How do I handle this situation properly?

**Details:**

I've got User and Role models with N-N relationship, and their DTOs.

I've got a UserController wherein I've got create/edit actions. Here's how Edit GET and POST actions look:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var model = userRepository.Get(id);
        LoadPossibleRoles();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserDTO model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            userRepository.InsertOrUpdate(model);
            userRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            LoadPossibleRoles();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

What `LoadPossibleRoles()` does is retrieve all roles from the repository, convert them to `SelectListItem`s and puts them in the viewbag(I should probably create a viewmodel or something but I'm unsure how to create/use one in my situation). It looks like this:

```
    private void LoadPossibleRoles()
    {
        var availableRoles = roleRepository.GetAll();

        var selectItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var role in availableRoles)
        {
            var listItem = new SelectListItem();
            listItem.Value = role.Id.ToString();
            listItem.Text = role.Name;
            selectItems.Add(listItem);
        }            
        ViewBag.PossibleRoles = selectItems;
    }
```

I've got a _CreateOrEdit partial view whose model is UserDTO In which I've got _SingleRoleEdit partial for each added role. It looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:insertNewRole()" class="insert-new-role">Add a role</a>

@foreach( var r in Model.Roles)
{
    @Html.Partial("_SingleRoleEdit", r)
}
```

The `insertNewRole()` js function is an ajax call which calls "CreateNewRole" method in the UserController. The method looks like this:

```
    public PartialViewResult CreateNewRole()
    {
        LoadPossibleRoles();
        return PartialView("_SingleRoleEdit", new RoleDTO());
    }
```

And finally in `_SingleRoleEdit` partial I generate the dropdown list for all available roles:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Roles"))
{
    <table class="editor-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Role</th>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor( r => r.Id, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PossibleRoles))</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeItem(this);">X</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Presentationally this works as it should. I can add/remove dropdownlists which actually do show all available roles. The 'issue' is the way the data binding currently works. `DropDownListFor` binds the selected value in the dropdownlist to the models Id, however there is currently nothing binding the name to the text of the dropdownlist and that's why my `ModelState` is always invalid on Post. I'm aware that binding the text of the selection in the dropdownlist to the model is a bad idea. So I'm looking for a proper way to handle this situation.

Comment: If `Role.Name=null` if causing a model state error, I assume you have an attribute on the Role.Name property that prevents null or empty strings? and if so, is there a reason it cant be removed?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Indeed, I have a `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` annotation over my RoleDTO.Name property which I completely forgot about. I can remove the annotation and It'll probably work but the bigger question I have is: is that a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: Assuming you are only saving User.Role.ID to the database, and then your immediately redirecting, do you really need the name property? I suggest not, but you could create a hidden input ('@HiddenFor(r=>r.Name)`, then in the select's change event, get the selected option and assign it to the input - let me know if you need a code example.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Currently before saving the user I extract the gathered Id's and then replace the role collection with the roles gathered from the db which fit the gathered Id's. That is in my opinion a terrible way of doing things. I should probably make some ViewModel and collect selected dropdown values into some int collection or something instead of using RoleDTO, however I don't know how to do that(since I'm using BeginCollectionItem)

Comment: It sounds like you have a User class that contains IEnumerable<Role>?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, though in presentation layer I don't use pure entites, I use DTO's instead so UserDTO contains IEnumerable<RoleDTO>